# How to lock down Android tablet to only allow one app to run

Tags: android, locking

I am looking at locking down several Android Tablets (Samsung Galaxy tab) to allow the user to unlock the device and be sent straight into one application and not allowed to leave. I was wondering if this is possible without creating a custom ROM and if so how? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why was this question closed? I'm also looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try creating a custom launcher and see how far that gets you.  I don't think it will be bulletproof but by adding some hacks like having it auto-launch a specific app, it's probably about as far as you can get without a custom ROM.  See here for the code of the stock Android launcher:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/Launcher.java

Comment: you are supposed to put code on site.  Your link doesnt work

Comment: @Jon I can't copy the entire codebase for the Android launcher onto SO...I've updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an app that is more or less "non-exitable" by overriding the hardware buttons' default behaviour in your application.

Although if your app crashes and doesn't automatically restart after a crash, the user has full access to the rest of the system.